# understanding nested generic classes in C# with quiz

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, nested

While talking with a colleague about C#, he showed me some C# code which I had to predict the output of. This looked simple in the first place, but it wasn't. I can not really understand why C# acts this way.

The code:

```
public class A<T1>
{
    public T1 a;

    public class B<T2> : A<T2>
    {
        public T1 b;

        public class C<T3> : B<T3>
        {
            public T1 c;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A<int>.B<char>.C<bool> o = new A<int>.B<char>.C<bool>();

        Console.WriteLine(o.a.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(o.b.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(o.c.GetType());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
System.Boolean
System.Char
System.Int32
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I understand that `o.a` is of type bool because `C<T3>` inherits from `B<T3>` and `B<T2>` inherits from `A<T2>`. And I can also slightly understand that `o.c` is of type int because the type of `c` is `T1` which it gets from the outer class (I think).

My head is almost exploding when I try to figure out why `o.b` is of type char. Can some one explain this to me?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not maintaining the code at your company.

Comment: Interesting, but total overkill for anything practical. Im assuming this is academic rather than for work ?

Comment: @Default Why? Because they like to quiz each other on strange C# code?

Comment: @Erix someone must have figured this out based on something and I guess it came from some production code. And also no, I'm not too fond of being quizzed on something that I see no practical usage of..

Comment: @default isn't that what quizes are about in the first place?

Comment: Where as doing : public class B<T2> : A<int> gives expected results, interesting.

Comment: adding a fourth class shows clearly it works as stack

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is an old puzzle, and it is quite difficult. When I gave it to Anders himself he didn't get the answer right the first time!

I think the version your coworker gave you is from Cyrus's blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cyrusn/archive/2005/08/01/446431.aspx

A slightly simpler version is on my blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/07/27/an-inheritance-puzzle-part-one.aspx

The solution to my version is here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/07/30/an-inheritance-puzzle-part-two.aspx

Briefly, the reason for the confusing behaviour is that when you have a name that exists both in an outer class and a base class, the base class "wins". That is, if you have:

```
public class B
{
  public class X {}
} 
public class P
{
  public class X
  {
    public class D : B
    {
      public class N : X {}
    }
  }
}
```

Then `P.X.D.N` inherits from `B.X`, not from `P.X`. The puzzle makes nested generic types in such a way that the same declaration can be named via both the "outer" and "base" search paths, but has *different* meanings in each because of generic construction.

Anyway, read the explanation on the blog posts, and if its still not clear, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, my first answer was wrong. The nesting is important:

in `o.b.GetType()` b is the member of the surrounding class which is instantiated as `B<char>` which inherits from `A<char>` which in turn makes T1 equal to char.
What's not quite clear is the following (manual instantiation for `A_int.B_char.C_bool`):

```
public class A_bool
{
    public bool a;

    public class B_bool : A_bool
    {
        public bool b;
    }
}

public class A_char
{
    public char a;

    public class B_bool : A_bool
    {
        public char b;
    }
}

public class A_int
{
    public int a;

    public class B_char : A_char
    {
        public int b;

        public class C_bool : A_char.B_bool
        {
            public int c;
        }
    }
}
```

Here `C_bool` could have been derived from A_bool.B_bool as well, right? But since we're nested in `A_char` that's preferred.

Comment: Then why is o.c not a bool? Because C<bool> inherits from B<bool> which in turn inherits from A<bool>..

Comment: Yes what's confusing is the difference between inheritance and enclosing types. `C<bool>` is enclosed in `B<char>` but inherits from `B<bool>`

Comment: This is a nice way to illustrate the situation!